# javascript Split - Alternate to look behind

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string as below

> This | is a sample \| string

I would like to split the above string based on | and do not split where | is escaped. (\|).
How do I do that using javascript.

*Note:* I have come up with the below regular expression.

```
(?<!\\)\|
```

But Javascript does not support **look behind**

Comment: Your string should be `This | is a sample \\| string`, in that case you can use `/[^\\]\|/`

Comment: @elclanrs that would remove the space after `This`

Comment: @nderscore: You're right, in that case you could capture it, and then join, like `str.split(/([^\\])\|/)`. But it's not the best regex I suppose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform a match instead of a split:

```
> 'This | is a sample \\| string'.match(/([^\\|]|\\\|?)+/g)

["This ", " is a sample \| string"]
```

The above matches:

1. neither a backslash nor pipe character, or
2. if a backslash, an optional pipe character

Comment: Hi jack, There is one more issue with the above expression. Example string "This | is || sample string".  I need to get the result as ["This "," is ",""," sample string"]